# facebook application in heroku error

Tags: facebook, git, heroku

I am creating a facebook application and I am using this Heroku for the first time as I was following the procedure provided in the link [instruction](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook). While deploying to Heroku, the third step in instruction i.e. pushing the modified code up to Heroku with

`git push heroku master`

it throws a following error

`To git@heroku.com:xxxxxxxx.git
![rejected]             master -> master(non-fast - forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xxxxxxxxxx.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g 'git pull') before pushing again. See the 
'Note about fast-forwards' sections of 'git push --help' for details.`

Please give me the solution!!

Comment: Have you tried what the message suggests? – _“Merge the remote changes (e.g 'git pull') before pushing again.”_

Comment: tried but its still giving the same message

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `git`. You can't push to a server if your locale version is outdated.

The simple way to go would be to pull first:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "add my locale files"
git pull heroku master
# All goes well or you have a merge conflict (if so, you resolve conflicts). Then:
git push heroku
```

Comment: Hey Simon, it again throws a message: 
The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

Comment: You have to add and commit your file before. - edited the response

Comment: I have added and committed before performing the pull operation or Do i need to do it again?

Comment: call `git status` and make sure your working directory is clear

Comment: Simon, `git status` performed and displaying modified folder and untracked files and at the end of the message: `no changes added to commit`

Comment: So you didn't add and commit before pulling. Read my answer again, I added how to add and commmit your files.

Comment: Simon, can you explain What is `git add -A`?

Comment: the -A flag add all new, modified and removed file in your staged area. It's the state of this staged area who's committed with git commit.